# "TextureView cannot be cast to ViewGroup" due to Child Component

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native

Within my React Native Android app I create a custom Camera View component within Java by creating a `SimpleViewManager<TextureView>` class

```
public class CameraView extends SimpleViewManager<TextureView>{
   @Override
   public TextureView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext context) {
     textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(textureListener);
     return textureView;
   }
   // further listener functions to handle my workflow
}
```

My CameraManagerPackage.java looks like the following

```
public class CameraManagerPackage implements ReactPackage {
   @NonNull
   @Override
   public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(@NonNull ReactApplicationContext reactContext){
      List<NativeModule> nativeModules = new ArrayList<>();
      return nativeModules;
   }

   @Override
   public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
      return Arrays.<ViewManager>asList(
         new CameraView(reactContext)
      );
   }
}
```

Then I create my `CameraView` within a separate `.js` using `requireNativeComponent('CameraView', CameraManagerPackage , {});` and using the render to set my `CameraView`

```
class CameraManagerPackage extends React.PureComponent<Props>{
...
   render() {
      return <CameraView {...this.props}></CameraView>
   }
}
export default CameraManagerPackage ;
```

And within my main component I finially use my `CameraView` by importing it `import CameraView from './CameraView.js';` and including it into my render function

```
...
   render() {
      return <CameraView style={styles.cameraView}>
         <Text = style{styles.text}>test</Text>
      </CameraView>
   }
}
```

My problem is that I cannot use the `<Text ...>` line because it seems my CameraView/android.view.TextureView does not accept children components, without  this line the CameraView displays my camera output as expected. Using the `<Text ...>` creates the following error message:

```
android.view.TextureView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
```

Do I have to modify my `TextureView` to accept children components/is it possible to create a simple `ViewGroup` that fulfills my needs so I can add children components within react native?

**EDIT1:**
I renamed my `CameraView.java` to `CameraViewManager.java` (+ also the contructor and within `CameraManagerPackage.java` the line `new CameraViewManager(reactContext)`). But I still leave

```
public static final String REACT_CLASS = "CameraView";
public static final String ComponentTag= "CameraView";
```

My `CameraView.js` is now called `NativeCamera.js` and the contents are now only

```
import { requireNativeComponent } from "react-native";
module.exports = requireNativeComponent("NativeCamera");
```

Within my `Main.js` I import my custom component with

```
import NativeCamera from './NativeCamera.js';
...
render() {
   return(
      <NativeCamera style={styles.cameraStyle}>
         <Text></Text> // empty <View></View> works here, but also throws the same error when setting style
      </NativeCamera>
   )
}
```

All adaptions are according to this example: https://blog.logrocket.com/build-native-ui-components-react-native/. But it is still not working and I get this error:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `TextureView` cannot accept any child components, to display a button on top of the `TextureView` it is necessary to use the `position: 'absolute'` style property.